# Java smallest partition of common elements (in the same order) of two or more lists

Tags: java, list, matching

I'm looking for a quick and smart way to find up until where two lists are equal. In other words I need to find the smallest partition containing common elements in the same order of two or more lists. 
It might sound a bit confusing but here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
List 1: A, B, C, L, M Z
List 2: A, B, C, K, F
Output -> List 3: A, B, C
```

I need to use this in a recursive method which should be called with large inputs and all the solutions I've come up with are a bit too slow.

Thanks for your answers in advance

---

EDIT:
Please excuse me for being unclear. This is my first question and english is not my first language.

Let me explain the problem in a better way. I need to find the intersection of two or more lists starting from the first element of the lists. Please note that elements must be in the same order so it's not exactly an intersection but more like a partition.

the "recursive" thing was just to say that I need to include this in a recursive method which will run many times so I would like the solution to be as fast as possibile as to not lose a lot of time.

Working on an answer that appears to have been deleted I came up with my own solution:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ciao", "come"));
    List<String>  list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ciao", "come", "va"));
    List<String>  list3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ciao", "come", "va", "?", "tutto", "ok"));
    List<List<String>> allLists = new ArrayList<>();
    allLists.addAll(Arrays.asList(list1, list2, list3));

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int listIndex = 0;
    for(List<String> list : allLists){
        if(min > list.size()){
            min = list.size();
            listIndex = allLists.indexOf(list);
        }
    }


    int index = 0;
    boolean same = true;
    while(index<min && same == true) {
        String element = allLists.get(listIndex).get(index);
        for(List<String> list : allLists){
            if(!list.get(index).equals(element)){
                same = false;
                break;
            }
            element = allLists.get(listIndex).get(index);
        }
        if(same == true) ++index;
    }
    System.out.println("OUTPUT:" + allLists.get(listIndex).subList(0, index));
----> Output:  ciao, come
```

---

EDIT2:

And also garnful's solution works like a charm and I find it way clearer than mine. Thanks everybody

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: So the algorithm has to be recursive?

Comment: @Mr.Blue what have you tried thus far? Is there any code you've tried that you can add to your question?

Comment: Ah... did not saw the recursive part :(

Comment: The smallest partition of common elements is just a list of a single element in all lists, isn't it?

Comment: I agree, @AndyTurner. Maybe the title should say subList. Also, it's not clear if the elements need to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work, and hopefully be quite okay regarding the performance:

```
public List<String> getEqualsPart(List<String>[] listsToCheck) {
    if (listsToCheck.length == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    int minLength = getShortesListLength(listsToCheck);
    if (minLength == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return getEqualPartsForIndex(listsToCheck, 0, minLength, new ArrayList<String>());

}

private int getShortesListLength(List<String>[] listsToCheck) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (List<String> currentList : listsToCheck) {
        min = Math.min(min, currentList.size());
    }
    return min;
}

private List<String> getEqualPartsForIndex(List<String>[] listsToCheck, int index, int minLength,
        List<String> result) {
    if (index == minLength) {
        return result;
    }
    Set<String> setForIndex = new HashSet<>();
    Arrays.stream(listsToCheck).forEach(list -> setForIndex.add(list.get(index)));
    if (setForIndex.size() > 1) {
        return result;
    } else {
        result.add(setForIndex.iterator().next());
        return getEqualPartsForIndex(listsToCheck, index + 1, minLength, result);
    }

}`
```

Comment: The perfomance for this solution is only good if the input Lists are ArrayLists. If this is not the case, a well-performing solution gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: Exactly what I needed except for the fact that the method itself dind't necessarily have to be recursive. My bad, I explained my question very poorly but it works like a charm. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public List<E> equalUntil(List<E> l1, List<E> l2) {
    return equalUntilRec(l1.iterator(), l2.iterator(), new ArrayList<E>());
}

private int equalUntilRec(Iterator<E> it1, Iterator<E> it2, List<E> acc) {
    if(!it1.hasNext() || !it2.hasNext()) {
        return acc;
    } else {
        E e1 = it1.next();
        E e2 = it2.next();
        if(!e1.equals(e2)) {
            return acc;
        } 
        acc.add(e1);
        return equalUntilRec(it1, it2, acc);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method itself does not need to be recursive, and it must return a list, not an `int`, according to OP.